# hyperlink open a new window in ipad safari browser if target in same window also. Have to avoid new window

Tags: ios, ipad

In the html page, I have the hyperlink `<a>` tag. when clicking the PC browser like Firefox, IE that will open a link in same window. But same code if open in a iPad Safari browser, it will open a new window.

```
<div class="title-page-header">
    <img width="122" height="68" src="Gray2.svg" class="header-logo"><a href="index.php?cmd=logout" target="_self" class="logout-button">ログアウト</a>
</div>
```

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Check with <.. target="" >

Comment: already done it... but the problem is same...